# Does $E$ really equal $mc^2$? If mass is sped up to the speed of light, does the mass become energy?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, mass-energy

I'm currently in a debate with a co-worker.

Does $E$ really equal $mc^2$?

If mass is sped up to the speed of light, does the mass become energy?

Comment: If you're having an argument about the FTL mechanism in Star Trek, that has been covered already in [this other question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/271/2287). In short, it is an [Alcubierre drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive), which does not actually involve moving faster than light in the local space of the warp bubble. The expansion and contraction of space around the bubble moves it at faster than light speeds.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I had to fiddle with in on my end to show up as 'migrated' and not 'closed' and I guess because the name was changed on this end it reposted it.

Comment: This should be closed.  It's a double-post, and not a particularly high-quality question anyways.

Answer (score 10):

This is too naive, as far as physics goes, question and the title asks a different question than the body.  The short answer is *yes* for "Does $E$ really equal $mc^2$", and *no* for "If mass is sped up to the speed of light, does the mass become energy".
This is due to the fact that there are two uses of the word "mass" in physics, depending on context.

Read on:

Rest mass is a characteristic measure of matter. When we talk of elementary particles mass is the rest mass of each, $m_0$ which does not change no matter how fast it is going.

$E=mc^2$ either means $E=m_0 c^2$ for an object at rest, or $E=m_{rel} c^2$ when the object is moving.

The equation $E = m_{rel} c^2$ holds for moving objects. When the velocity is small, the relativistic mass and the rest mass are almost exactly the same.

It is the relativistic mass which grows with the velocity,

$$m_{rel}=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

and is due to the kinetic energy given to the particle, the rest mass does not change. From the formula it is evident that a massive particle can only incrementally approach the velocity of light, never equal it; even approaching it, enormous amounts of kinetic energy would be needed. Further reading in the [wiki article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rest_mass_energy)

**Edit** after comments in recent answer by @Ron Maimon .

Studies in nuclear and particle physics as well as in astrophysics have established that even though our lives are lived in non relativistic environments, relativity rules from the microcosm up. This view becomes organized by the use of four-vectors, which distinguishes  two masses:

a) into an invariant part,$m_{0}$ that characterizes a body, in the same way that a length characterizes a ruler in three dimensions,

and b) a relativistic mass $m_{rel}$ that includes the energy that a body has due to motion.

At rest the two masses are equal, and in our everyday world where velocities are much smaller than $c$ indistinguishable experimentally.

In this language all mass is energy,  from $E = m_{rel} c^2$,

one sees that  $E/c^2 = m_{rel} $

for all velocities, since $c$  is constant. So the answer  is that a **material body is energy from 0 speed on**, and this  does not change for very high speeds except as increase in energy. Only the kinetic part of this energy is available in the non relativistic everyday world.

Thus the real physics answer is neither yes nor no.

Comment: Hm, I always wondered if the mass equivalence principle means the gravitational mass is equivalent to the rest mass or to the relativistic mass, i.e. would a pulk of fast electrons "weigh" more?

Comment: @Tobias the mass equivalence applies to the mass characterizing the four vector of the system under consideration, m=sqrt(E^2-p2), the invariant mass  of the system. Yes, a bunch of electrons would have as a limit the sum of their masses, but collectively would be heavier according to the formula.

Comment: should add that the p in p^2 is the vector sum of the electron momenta, and the square is the dot product of the sum with itself.

Comment: so in theory if you accelerate enough mass you have a gravity generator? I'm somehow doubting that since it hasn't happened yet, but maybe it'd just require too much energy... I should post a separate question tomorrow

Comment: You could think of it that way. Take the delta resonance, as an example, it is a proton-pi resonance, its mass is 1232mev, it is created by a pion and a nucleon whose additive mass is less then this.~ (938+140=1078)

Comment: @Anna, the question says "sped up to the speed of light". So could you edit your answer to remind the OP that it is not possible for an object with non-zero rest mass to get all the way **to** the speed of light. Then I will +1...

Comment: @FrankH done, you are right, one should address this.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. $E = m c^2$ holds only for massive objects at rest. When they move this relation no longer holds. The more generic energy-mass-momentum relationship does hold in these situations:

$$E^2 = m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2$$

In this equation, $m$ is the invariant mass, $E$ the total energy, and $p$ the momentum. When the object with invariant mass $m$ speeds up, $E$ and $p$ both increase, while $m$ stays the same as what it is at rest. Hence its name 'rest mass'.

Comment: Doesn't $E = m c^2$ still apply if $m$ is taken to be the *relativistic* mass (which increases with increasing speed)?

Comment: And what is the physical meaning of relativistic mass (other than energy scaled by the speed of light)? Lev Okun refers to relativistic mass as a pedagogical virus. He is absolutely right. See: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0602037

Comment: Yeah, relativistic mass is an outdated concept. These days we just call it "energy" (and work in natural units if people start complaining about missing factors of $c$ :-P). (Excellent answer by the way)

Answer (score 1):

No.
Mass can be converted into energy(it happens in e.g. the sun and in a nuclear power plant), and energy into mass(e.g. the big bang).
An other form of energy is motion energy(called kinetic energy) it increases as the object is accelerated toward the speed of light(the maximum speed).

Comment: This "motion energy" registers on a scale, and gravitates objects towards it--- a box of photons weighs more, and an electron going fast in a circle in a magnetic field weighs more.

Comment: Pushing forward the big bang as an example of energy-mass conversion is highly dependent on interpretation (to say the least), and from didactical perspective will probably create more questions than it answers.

Comment: The whole "conversion" idea is idiotic. -1 There is no conversion of mass to energy, the thing we call mass colloquially _is_ the energy. The new quantity of rest mass in relativity is not the right idea of mass.

Comment: I do not agree the conversion idea is not idiotic. The fermions( half-integer spin particles) that obey the Fermi–Dirac statistics(and thereby seen as matter) is indeed converted into energy in an annihilation(the word itself also suggest the disappearance of the matter).

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen But are "matter" and "mass" the same thing?

Comment: @Michael: No. Matter has mass. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $E=mc^2$ always, for everything, because what we call "mass" colloquially is just the energy contained in something. The quantity physicists call "mass" nowadays is the mass as measured when travelling along with something, and this is the rest-mass. But the rest-mass is not what weighs on a scale, nor is it what you feel as resistance to pushing, nor is it additive to give the mass of a composite system, nor is it the source of gravity. The energy (divided by $c^2$) is all these things. When the energy is converted in units using $c$ to become a mass, it is called the "relativistic mass", which, when you choose units so that $c=1$, is just a synonym for energy.

Lev Okun has argued that the concept of "relativistic mass" is outdated, and pedagogically useless. He is completely wrong on this. Once a student understands that what you call "mass" day-to-day is really the energy (divided by $c^2$), that frees up the useful short word "mass" to mean something else, namely "rest mass", but not until you understand the equivalence of energy and colloquial mass.

Comment: the question is "If mass is sped up", and "does the mass become energy", so a yes is not an appropriate answer to a naive and confused question. The "mass" in the question is the rest mass, as we know it in everyday life, where relativistic effects are infinitesimal.  The energy in m0 is inaccessible to everyday users, only becomes evident in nuclear physics and higher energies. Of course I agree with you that m is what enters all the physics studies where relativity effects are important and it is important for physics students to learn this. I do not think the questioner is a physicist.

Comment: continued: on the other hand the rest mass of a composite system is the invariant mass of the added four vectors of the system. Learning to work with four vectors is more to the point  than using convoluted formulae.

Comment: @anna v: If you speed something up, it weighs more. A box of hot gas (molecules sped up) weighs more than a box of cold gas. If you have an electron going around in circles, it weighs more than an electron at rest. The physics of "mass" is the physics of energy, and the "rest mass" is the physically less intuitive concept.

Comment: Ron -- I am sure we agree on all the physics, but I strongly disagree with you on your didactical views. The way you answer this question means that you are selling nothing more than an empty tautology. Let's cut the crap and explain to lay people the way it is: energy rules supreme. Energy is the source of gravity, and energy is inertia. Mass is the invariant associated with energy.

Comment: @Johannes: except this isn't true--- the thing we call "mass" is just the "energy divided by c^2", and I am sick of the confusions people have about mass-energy conversion (there was another question about whether fire converts mass to energy!). In order to cure this confusion, one must explain that the quantity we call "mass" is really "energy", and physicists hijacked the term "mass" to mean something else, namely rest-mass. The notion that rest-mass corresponds to the intuitive notion of mass is absurd.

Comment: Your argument is fine for physicists. For people outside it is confusing because relativistic effects are not relevant locally in the world we live unless working with nuclear physics energies and above. The highjacking is according to one's POV. Since invariant mass and relativistic mass at the velocities we move and breathe and live in is the same. Now the questioner has heard that "mass is energy" and is asking whether it becomes energy at very high velocities. The correct answer is that it is always energy except part of it is  inaccessible for utilization

Comment: @anna_v: The issue is that if you have a nonrelativistic object which is made up out of relativistic particles, then the nonrelativistc "mass" of the nonrelativistic object is the sum of the energies of the particles inside. This is why saying "mass is rest-mass" is confusing to lay-people, because lay-people believe mass is additive. Well energy is additive, and it has units of mass when c=1, but it isn't rest mass, and rest-mass isn't additive. So people get endlessly confused. I believe Tolman introduced relativistic mass to fix this pedagogical problem that rest-mass isn't additive.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the answer is "Yes", but only because of the way logical implication is defined; [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication).

*If* mass is sped up to the speed of light, then sure, mass does become energy (or a bowl of petunias, or the square root of existentialism).

The point is that the premise is not possible; speeding mass up to the speed of light would require infinite energy input.  Not just energy equivalent to the mass, via E = m c^2, but quite literally infinite.

The statement "If I'm 20 feet tall, then my name is Fred" is true, because I'm not 20 feet tall (the fact that my name isn't Fred is irrelevant).

But the answer to a better-phrased version of your question would probably be "No".  No matter how fast you accelerate a mass, the original rest mass is still there.

Comment: As much as I want to upvote for the mental image of a bowl of petunias busting out of the LHC tunnel, I think it's pretty misleading to start your answer off by saying "yes." Some fraction of the audience of this question may very well take that the wrong way. Given that the premise is impossible, all you can really say is that the answer is undefined.

Comment: I was referring to the meaning of if-then in logic.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication).

Comment: Yeah, I know about Boolean logic rules, but (most) people don't naturally think that way.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Then perhaps this is a good chance for them to learn.  (I've updated the answer for, I hope, better clarity.)

Comment: The only error in Keith's answer lies in the fact that he forgot that petunias are always accompanied by whales.