# $E=mc^2$ why is it $c^2$ and not just $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, units

Why is constant for the conversion of mass to energy square of the ligths speed? is it bedside it's the fastest real matter? .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does $E$ really equal $mc^2$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16233/does-e-really-equal-mc2)

Comment: Why? Why ask? This is the way it is. We get the best experimental predictions with this law, instead of any other one. That's why.

Comment: Sorry, but this question doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 12):

Because energy in joules, and joule is $\text{kg}\cdot\frac{\text{m}^2}{\text{s}^2}$ not $\text{kg}\cdot\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$.

Comment: Correct about always having  the needed units, but also add that it fits all experimental data up to  now.